# Can a 1-wire temperature sensor be easily turned into a PT100 or PT1000 sensor?

Tags: brewing, electric

I have a [1-wire sensor](https://store.brewpi.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1800x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/t/e/temp-sensor-threaded-ds18b20-2.jpg) which has the design I need and a hardware for working with PT100/PT1000 sensors. Can I turn the 1-wire sensor into a PT100/PT1000 sensor easily?

Note: this question has been raised during planning an electrical HERMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may want to ask this on the electronics stack exchange.

but to answer this here.

no, you cant replace a PT100 sensor, with a 1-wire temp sensor.

PT100/1000 are analog sensors, 1 wire sensors are digital.

as to convert a 1 wire, to an analog sensor, all depends on your knowledge of electronics, easy if you know a lot, hard if you dont know anything...

the way I would convert it would be to use a micro controller, like an msp430, to read the 1 wire, and then use <del>pwm or a DAC</del> Digital potentiometer to send the analog signal to your hardware.

Comment: Thanks, @jsolarski. AFAIU, PT100(0) sensors are simple, dump hardware while 1-wire adds significant logic to the sensor? Do you think there are chances that a 1-wire sensor could be reduced to PT100(0) by simply removing the logic piece? I've added a link to an image showing the sensor in question ... looks like you can screw off multiple parts ... so my naive thinking is whether I could simply screw off the 1-wire part?

Comment: no, it is still a digital temp sensor, it is one of these embedded into the probe. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/245 , so even if you screw parts off, the sensor is still digital. 

If your equipment requires PT100/0 then you may want to look at different hardware. or find a cheap sensor...... http://www.walmart.com/ip/PT100-Type-15cm-Probe-Thermocouple-Temperature-Sensor-Cable-3-Meters/45587889?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=142&adid=22222222227033246719&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=71935313816&wl4=&wl5=pla&wl6=119485694216&veh=sem#about
only $8.00 USD+S&H

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the two are very different - to make a OneWire sensor look like a PT100 sensor, you'd have to find some way to recreate the resistance in the wire that varies with temperature, which is how a PT100 works. The simplest way to do that would be to use a real PT100 sensor - emulating a PT100 sensor would be much harder and most likely introduce more error than just using a PT100.

On the other hand, can you change your sensing hardware to accept a OneWire sensor? See [brewpi.com](http://brewpi.com) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, @mdma. I think I have found a PT1000 sensor which has a similar design, so it can be mounted in a BSP 1/2 t-piece: http://www.aliexpress.com/item/PT1000-High-Temperature-Sensor-Platinum-Resistance-with-Silicone-Gel-wire-1-5m-length-1-2-SUS304/32347448286.html -- hopefully it will ship soon.